# Why a function in a dictionary that passes arguments is executed immediately?

Tags: python, function, oop

I'm fairly new to Python.

I was creating a script that performed a series of functions.

I don't know how many functions I would have done, so I opted for a menu on which the choices were based on a global dictionary, where the keys represent the user's input choice and the values the call to the associated function.

As seen in the following snippet, within the dictionary, there are several `func2` functions.

Initially I treated these functions individually (`func2`, `func3`, `func4`, ...). But I noticed that these repeated themselves following a common basic pattern. So, since I recently covered classes in OOP, I thought I could abstract these functions into a class.

The idea was to associate each `choices` key with a function to which I would, in the case of `func2`, pass the 'identifier' argument.

These arguments were already defined as key in another *nested dictionary* (`dict`). So, after calling the class constructor and creating a generic object, through the category, I would pass the single *nested dictionary* (`dict:{"CatA" : {sub_dict}, ... }`) to the method of that object that would produce a total and this would be printed along with the category it belongs to.

```py
#main.py
from menu import *

choices = {
 "1": func1,
 "2": func2("CategoryA"),
 "3": func2("CategoryB"),
 ...
 "7": func3,
 ...
}

def main():
 while True:
  printMenu()  # the print lines are set up like this: `num) description`
  choice = input("Enter choice: ")

  if choice == "0":
   break
  elif choice in choices:
   choices[choice]()
  else:
   print("Invalid Choice")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

```py
# menu.py
def func1():
 ...

def func2(category: str):
 from dict import extractDict
 from classfunc2 import ClassFunc2

 dict = extractDict()
 obj = ClassFunc2()
 total = obj.totNumber(**dict[category])
 obj.printResults(total,category)

def func3()
 ... 
 
def printMenu()
 ...
```

```py
# classfunc2.py
class ClassFunc2:
 def __int__(self):
  return

 def totNumber(self, **dict):
  ...
  a = input(smth)
  ...
  return total

 def printResults(self, total, category):
  print()
```

But here comes the problems:
when I run the script, for some reason unknown to me, ***only* all** instances of `func2` are executed before I can select them from the menu.
I'm very sure I did something wrong with the abstraction, but I don't know where at all.

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how should I fix this script?

PS: I know the title isn't accurate, but I didn't know what else to put. I would appreciate it if you could share some ideas on how to improve the title.

Comment: See [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). Also check out the [tour] for an intro to the site.

Comment: `ClassFunc2` contains invalid code. Please make a [mre].

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I will try to improve the question and try to improve the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your functions immediately when defining the dictionary and then save the return value of those functions within your dictionary. Let's say your function1 returns None. That would mean, that your function is first executed and then the value None would be saved in your dictionary instead of the function itself, because you called it with the parentheses.

Wrong: `func2("my argument")`

Instead of passing the output of the function you want to pass the function itself. Therefore you need to create a function that calls your function with the desired arguments.

A simple but verbose solution would look like this:

```
def call_func_2():
    func_2("my argument")

menu_dictionary = {"2": call_func_2}
```

Notice that the previous example does not call the function when initializing the dictionary.

A better approach would be using lambda functions. These are small one-liner functions, which allow you to wrap your function calls without having to define additional functions outside of your dictionary. In my opinion this is the cleanest approach and solves your problem in the most efficient way:

```
menu = {
    "1": func_1,
    "2": lambda: func_2("my param"),
    "3": lambda: func_3([1, 2, 3], "param")
}
```

Notice that wrapping your function call within a (lambda) function is not necessary if you don't want to pass arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
choises = {
 "1": func1,
 "2": func2("CategoryA"),
 "3": func2("CategoryB"),
 ...
 "7": func3,
 ...
}
```

Do you see the key difference in how the dictionary is using `func2` versus `func1` and `func3`?

The references to `func2` also have parentheses `()` after the function name, meaning the function is called *immediately*, and the returned value is stored in the dictionary.

But `func1` and `func3` do not have parentheses after, so the dictionary is storing the actual function objects, which are called *later*.

If you want `func2` to be called *later*, like `func1` and `func3`, then get rid of the parentheses in the dictionary definition.

EDIT:

If you want the dictionary to also contain arguments for some of the function calls, you can use `functools.partial()` to create a callable "bundle" with a function object and optionally some arguments:

```
from functools import partial

choises = {
 "1": partial(func1),
 "2": partial(func2, "CategoryA"),
 "3": partial(func2, "CategoryB"),
 ...
 "7": partial(func3),
 ...
}
```

Then you would just call the function object in the dict:

```
choises["2"]()
```

Comment: It's not enough to just get rid of the parentheses; the other difference between `func{1,3}` and `func2` is that `func2`, when called, needs to be called with a specific argument, whereas `func{1,3}` just need to be called with the "same" (non-existent) argument.

Comment: If I get rid of the parentheses, how can I then distinguish which option to choose? Will I have to create some kind of submenu?